# Reverted edit results in negative reputation?

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation, edits

Copied from https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com

Just a question ... some minutes ago my reputation was at "1665". An edit i made during the day was reverted by the questioneer, but insead of `+2` and `-2` I only see `-2 reverted` ... and reputation is at "1661" (instead of "1663")

Is this intented behavoir?

This "bug" was confirmed here: https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1204/46249

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the image there kind of explains this indirectly:

[image]

While one of your edits was reverted recently, another one of your edits was also deleted along with the parent post. The problem here is that the reputation for that deletion wasn't actually lost until much later. It actually wasn't subtracted from your profile until *after* the other edit was reverted and you self-deleted an answer, which finally scheduled you for a rep recalc. So the reversion dropped you down to 1663 and then shortly after the system finally caught up with that deleted post and subtracted another 2 for that edit to land you at 1661. That gives the appearance of unexpectedly losing 4 reputation at once, when in reality the second 2 reputation was lost hours ago but just never actually taken away.

Your reputation is completely correct as of 18:59 UTC today, which is when the system did a full recalc on your account.